# Do people have the right to comment or live blog professional sports in the United States?

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property, sport, entertainment-law

Do private persons have the freedom to live blog or comment on games on progress in professional sports?

For example, can a web caster watch the game on TV and then give his running commentary and graphics showing the score on his web site or on Twitch TV?

(Note I am not asking about rebroadcasting video, just about a person making their own commentary and graphics for the game. By a "graphic", I mean, for example, a box score in baseball.)

Comment: In [*NBA v. Motorola*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Basketball_Ass%27n_v._Motorola,_Inc.), the Second Circuit ruled in favor of a company that sold a pager service delivering live sports score updates.  But I don't know what further developments have taken place since then.

Comment: Related (and quoting the case Nate linked above): [How can the NFL assert copyright over “any pictures, descriptions, or accounts of the game”?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16947/how-can-the-nfl-assert-copyright-over-any-pictures-descriptions-or-accounts-o)

Comment: For a more notable question, can you give an indication as to why you think this might _not_ be the case?

Comment: Interesting... So one could essentially create a program, which records the player positions and creates a virtual rendering to indicate the current state of the game and broadcast this without copyright infingement, e.g. in a mobile app without paying any royalties...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See the question Jeffrey linked above your comment. NFL, MLB, etc. make statements to that effect during their telecasts, even if the accuracy of those statements is dubious.

Comment: @reirab I'm proposing that this information be incorporated into the question by its author

Comment: @Falco The more you veer from commentary to reproduction, the more likely it will be deemed a derivative work and thus infringing.

Comment: Why... why would they *not* have this right? What country are you from?

Comment: @only_pro the NFL specifically announces near the beginning of every game, "Any other use of this telecast or any pictures, descriptions, or accounts of the game without the NFL's consent is prohibited."  It's a reasonable legal question to ask whether that's enforceable.

Comment: @only_pro On top of Kevin's comment, laws in the US are often notoriously restrictive (due to nearly unlimited lobbying by corporations) across a multitude of subjects or fields when it comes to rights of the consumer. For example it is technically illegal (or at least, it used to be) to buy a CD of music and play it in a stereo system with other people present unless you have a license to rebroadcast.

Answer (score 17):

In the United States at least, the answer is clearly "Yes". Absent some restrictive agreement to which the would-be blogger is explicitly a party, a person has a protected right to comment or report on events and publish opinions of them. The question does not mention a location or jurisdiction, and I am  not suren what the law on this point might be in non-US jurisdictions.

Comment: There is the issue of trademarks, and specifically that if you use the trademarked term "Superbowl", in a context where anything like advertising or money changing hands might occur, the owners of that particular trademark are likely to come down on you like a ton of bricks. Technically, if you are just referring to it, you are [legally allowed to use the trademarked name](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2018/02/you-can-call-super-bowl-super-bowl), but often in the US the party with the biggest lawyers wins.

Comment: @T.E.D. "often in the US the party with the **deepest pockets** wins."  FTFY.  It doesn't matter how good your lawyer is if the other side can run out the clock (so to speak!) on your ability to pay them.

Comment: @T.E.D. And the people who own the trademark for "The Superbowl" are notorious for sending takedown notices after anyone and everything without regard for what their trademark actually covers to the point where a ton of people and companies have just stopped trying to fight it and now just refer to it as "the big game", which the NFL had tried to get the trademark for too, but was denied.

Comment: @MasonWheeler - I like my phrasing better, and it means essentially the same thing. This is one of those situations where "Well, acutally..."ing something just argues for making it less zippy without fundamentally enlightening the reader on the topic at hand.